# Ionic - Navigate to a Ionic Tabs page with a specific Id Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic-tabs

I'm working on an app that has the following use case which I'm not sure how to implement.

I'm on a page that display a list of Game/Match Results. When I click on that particular Game I want to be brought to a more detailed page for that Game, however this Detailed page is a tabs page (has 2 tabs on it).

Here's the code in my List of Games page:

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let match of matches; let i = index"  tappable routerLink="/../match-details/match-details-info/{{match.id}}"
```

Once I click on that ion-card I want to be brought to a page that has tabs - I imagine the URL should look something like /match-details/match-details-info/XYZ1234345 but I'm not sure how to get there.

Here is my match-details-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatchDetailsPage } from './match-details.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MatchDetailsPage,
    children: [

      {
        path: 'match-details-info/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-info/match-details-info.module#MatchDetailsInfoPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'match-details-lineup/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-lineup/match-details-lineup.module#MatchDetailsLineupPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
       {
        path: 'match-details-scorers/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-scorers/match-details-scorers.module#MatchDetailsScorersPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/match-details/match-details-info',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/match-details/match-details-info',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MatchDetailsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Here is the error I'm seeing

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'match-details/match-details-info/inhOKexG3AtcJNnj0xyW'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'match-details/match-details-info/inhOKexG3AtcJNnj0xyW'
```

The url looks correct to me but for some reason it can not match the route.

Also including part of the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/user/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'match-details/:id', loadChildren: './pages/match-details/match-details.module#MatchDetailsPageModule' },
  { path: 'player-details/:id', loadChildren: './pages/player-details/player-details.module#PlayerDetailsPageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  //{ path: 'admin-home-tabs, loadChildren: './pages/admin-home-tabs/admin-home-tabs.module#AdminHomeTabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'reset-password', loadChildren: './pages/reset-password/reset-password.module#ResetPasswordPageModule' },
```

Answer (score 1):

On your routes you can include the `/:id` in the path of the `match-details-info` page as below, this will indicate that the page accepts an id parameter

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MatchDetailsPage,
    children: [

      {
        path: 'match-details-info/:id',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-info/match-details-info.module#MatchDetailsInfoPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'match-details-lineup',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-lineup/match-details-lineup.module#MatchDetailsLineupPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
       {
        path: 'match-details-scorers',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../match-details-scorers/match-details-scorers.module#MatchDetailsScorersPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/match-details/match-details-info',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/match-details/match-details-info',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  } 
];
```

The `routerLink` on your `ion-card` should then include the `match-details-info` path to navigate directly to the tab, you should then also move the code to get the id from to the match-details-info page

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let match of matches; let i = index"  tappable routerLink="/../match-details/match-details-info/{{match.id}}"
```

Comment: Thanks again @Bart - The url looks as I'd expect but I'm getting the following error:

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'match-details/match-details-info/inhOKexG3AtcJNnj0xyW'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'match-details/match-details-info/inhOKexG3AtcJNnj0xyW'

Comment: can you double check you match-details-info path that it includes the /:id that is the only thing still that I can see might cause the route match error, can you maybe update your original post to include the main routing paths just to make sure all is good there

Comment: I've tried a few different changes in my match-details-routing.module.ts but unfortunately I'm still seeing the same issue in the comment above. The url looks how I expect it to look - correct id etc.